# Mapping value to id in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

My code looks like

```
<select [(ngModel)]="">
                    <option value="1">New York</option>
                    <option value="2"Phoenix</option>
                    <option value="3">Boston</option>
                </select>
```

What should I put in `[(ngModel)]` so that my database has the values (the city ids - say `1`), but when I retrieve it, it displays `New York` on the page in the drop down?

I store it as `cityId` in the database?

Comment: Are you getting a collection/array/list of city items from something like a REST API when the component loads that has numeric id and string text values for each city you are looking to display?

Comment: No. These values are always hardcoded on the HTML. They won't change

Answer (score 0):

The `[(ngModel)]` binding can be tied to **any** property on your component. You can then reference that property in methods executed on the component to submit to remote resources such as RESTful API or similar.

For a `<select>` dropdown, the `[(ngModel)]` will be tied to the select `value` property of the given `<option>`. Simply create a property on your class such as `cityId: number;` and put that into the `[(ngModel)]="cityId"`. Then reference the `cityId` in methods via `this.cityId` which you can send to the API/database or whatever you need. You can set the value of the dropdown via updating the `cityId` property numeric value such as `this.cityId = 2` and the `<select>` within the view will update accordingly.

Here is a contrived example and a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6F3EbeliMt8OM9KqvS3h?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview) demonstrating the functionality. I'd recommend putting the template in a separate file. It's hard to see exactly what you need without additional information regarding your forms, models, and application structure.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="cityId">
        <option value="-1">Select city...</option>
        <option value="1">New York</option>
        <option value="2">Phoenix</option>
        <option value="3">Boston</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <div>Select City Id: {{cityId}}</div>

    <br />

    <button type="button" (click)="doSomethingWithCityValues()">Click Me</button>

    <br />
    <br />

    <button type="button" (click)="setCityValue()">Click Me</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
   cityId: number = -1;

   doSomethingWithCityValues() {
     // you can use cityId value via this.cityId
     console.log(this.cityId);
   }

   setCityValue() {
     this.cityId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
   }
}
```

Hopefully this helps!